# iOS(iPhone) Apps is compatible with ipad. But how?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, compatibility

we have been developing many ios app as a team. And we always choose specific device type such as iPhone not Universal app or iPad.
[image]

And the question is,Our some app is say "Compatible with iPhone, iPad and iPod touch." and some other app say "Compatible with iPhone and iPod touch."

A App on AppStore
[image: A App on AppStore]

B App on AppStore
[image: B App on AppStore]

How does Apple decide compatiple device familly?

Which code block causes this difference?

Comment: This information may help you [UIDeviceFamily Key](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW11)

Comment: Thank you for your response @Raviprakash . i checked, it's look like normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. We use Healtykit.framework in some project. And this freamework is only available on iPhone not iPad. if you choose required option in the "Link With Binary in Library", the app store description is say "compatible with iPhone and iPod touch".

[image]
 if you want to available for the iPad, you should choose optional from the "Link With Binary in Library"

[HealthKit and the Health app are unavailable on iPad.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit)

Comment: Is there any other framework in iOS which behaves in the same way.? I mean unavailable either on iPhone or iPad.

Comment: Theoretically MessageUI.freamework should not work  on iPad, but in our projects MessageUI.freamework is required, but in the App Store is available for iPad. So, i do not know which .framework causes your problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you have noticed Info.plist file there is 1 property called "Application requires iPhone environment". Its a BOOL type of property.

So if this property set to YES in plist file than even if you have selected devices to iPhone as in your screenshot it will show compatibility with iPad.

And if this Property Set for NO than it will not show compatibility with iPad.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you @Mayur. But this is not working. "Application requires iPhone environment" property is YES, and selected device is iPhone, but some apps is still says "iPad" compatible and some other not.